# Strange issue with query design function in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the error message "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" in a query I am making using query builder in access. The problem is caused by a function inside the query.

This is the function :

```
Function Sudent_Selected_Next_Active_Season(Code_Student, Starting_Date As Date, Code_Project) As Boolean

    Dim MyReturn
    Dim SQLDate
    SQLDate = Format$(Starting_Date, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")

    MyReturn = DCount("[code_student]", "Project_Termination_level_2", "[Code_Student]=" & Code_Student & " and [ending] > " & SQLDate & " and [code_project] <>" & Code_Project)

    If IsNull(MyReturn) Then
        MyReturn = 0
    End If

    If MyReturn > 0 Then
        Sudent_Selected_Next_Active_Season = True
    Else
        Sudent_Selected_Next_Active_Season = False
    End If

End Function
```

I tried as criteria 0, -1, "0", "-1", True, False and they all give the same error.

If I remove the criteria and I review the data, all the row are composed of -1 and 0

This is the SQL used.

```
SELECT Sudent_Selected_Next_Active_Season([t_student].[code_student],[T_Project].[starting_date],[T_project].[code_project]) AS ActiveNextSeason
FROM (T_Project INNER JOIN T_Project_Student ON T_Project.Code_Project = T_Project_Student.Code_Project) INNER JOIN T_Student ON T_Project_Student.Code_Student = T_Student.Code_Student
WHERE (((Sudent_Selected_Next_Active_Season([t_student].[code_student],[T_Project].[starting_date],[T_project].[code_project]))=-1)) OR (((Sudent_Selected_Next_Active_Season([t_student].[code_student],[T_Project].[starting_date],[T_project].[code_project]))=-1));
```

If anyone could give me an idea of where to search for a solution I would appreciate it. If anyone wants more information please just ask.

Comment: Why `Code_Student` and `Code_Project` doesn't have `as DataType` in the function call signature?

Comment: You should also add the query SQL where you use the function.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza I made the changes but it did not fix it.

Comment: You would really help yourself (when you read the function the next time) and us, if you'd specify the data types of `Code_Student` and `Code_Project` in your function. Are they numbers?

Comment: These are integer the are ID of their respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you have the same condition twice in your `WHERE` clause, but in general, with those errors, you need to convert the data type on one side to match the other.
You could change the return value of your function to `integer`, cast the `boolean` return value to `integer`, or cast the -1 as `boolean`.

If you've changed the return value of the function to an integer, then the comparison with -1 should not give you a data type conversion error.  Try this:

```
SELECT  
    s.code_student,p.starting_date,p.code_project,
    Sudent_Selected_Next_Active_Season(s.code_student,p.starting_date,p.code_project) AS ActiveNextSeason
FROM 
    T_Project p INNER JOIN 
    T_Project_Student ps    ON 
    p.Code_Project = ps.Code_Project INNER JOIN 
    T_Student s ON 
    ps.Code_Student = s.Code_Student
WHERE
 Sudent_Selected_Next_Active_Season(s.code_student,p.starting_date,p.code_project)=-1
```

Comment: I have it twice because this is the simplified query where I removed everything except the problem. The function is of value type boolean alrealdy.

Comment: right, that's the problem.  you're comparing a boolean to an integer.  try changing the return type to an integer.

Comment: I have changed the MyReturn and Sudent_Selected_Next_Active_Season to be of type integer but still the same issues